# Why does Kotlin implicitly call getters and setters for properties?

Tags: kotlin

What is the purpose of Kotlin's implicit calling of getter/setter functions for properties when you try to access them? Isn't the point of getter and setters already that you can easily call them if you intend to use them? Kotlin's version basically just introduces an additional complexity with the 'field' identifier and introduces weirdness like the following, where an object may not behave like its interface intended:

```
interface Counter {
    var count: Int
    fun increment() {
        count = count + 1
    }
}

class WeirdCounter: Counter {
    override var count: Int = 0
        get() = field
        set(value) {println("ignore the value")}
}
```

Just trying to understand the intent behind this.

Comment: You could write a "weird" setter if there were no properties and just getter/setter functions as well. I think the primary reason is that it is good practice in Java to encapsulate fields by making them private and exposing getters/setters. This allows you to modify their behavior later if you need to without breaking code that uses the class. So properties enforce this and make it more concise to access them. And the vast majority of the time, you can use the default implementation of a simple backing field.

Comment: And you never have to remember if a field has to be modified or retrieved through the getter/setter vs. the field. I don't see the `field` as extra complexity. If you were implementing a getter and setter in Java, you'd need a backing field, but you'd be responsible for naming it, keeping it private, and remembering whether it's one that should not be modified directly except through its setter function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way Kotlin implements properties using getters and setters is basically what's common practice — and best practice — in many other languages.

‘Bare’ fields, as in Java, are simple, clear, and easy to use; but **bare fields have problems**:

- They expose an implementation detail (the field, and especially its type), preventing it from being changed in future.
- They don't allow the class to control its own state.

Of course, these aren't a problem for simple value classes.  But for more complex classes, they can be a real problem.

For example, you may want to change the way a class stores its state (e.g. replacing a `long` with a `BigDecimal`), but if that class is part of a popular library's public interface then thousands of users would get pretty annoyed.

Or suppose it would be really convenient if you could ensure that a String property was always stored in lower-case without leading or trailing whitespace.  But with a ‘bare’ property there's no way to enforce that.

**So the usual pattern is to have a field** that's private, and only accessible from within the class itself (which you control); **and provide accessor methods**.

That gives you full control.  You can change the internal representation, as long as you update the accessor methods to convert to/from the new form as needed.  And your setter can do any normalisation, formatting, or whatever to enforce any restrictions on the state.

**However, in languages like Java, that's more awkward and long-winded** than a simple field: accessor methods turn a one-line field into seven lines (excluding blank lines, and excluding doc comments, so that's probably more like turning 3 lines into 21).  And while calling a getter method is only a few characters longer (with `get` and `()`) than referencing a field, calling a setter is a lot less intuitive than a simple assignment.

The result is that either developers do the right thing and fill their classes with boilerplate (with all the implications for maintainability and risk of error), or they don't bother and risk the problems above.

**Kotlin, though, gives the best of both worlds**: a simple property *looks* just like a field, both when defining and when accessing it.  So you get the lean, concise, clear code.  But it's *implemented* with a private backing field (if needed) and accessor method(s)s, so you get all the advantages of those too.  And if you ever need to add validation or change the representation or log all access or whatever, you have the option of replacing the default accessors with your own implementations.

Your `WeirdCounter` example is odd, but not as scary (or as likely) as you might think.  In an object-oriented language, a class is master of its own state, and other classes generally don't and *shouldn't* know about its internals.  (That way, they're insulated from changes to those internals.)  If a class needs to do something counter-intuitive in a setter, that's only a concern if it breaks the class's contract — but that would be a bug, and should become obvious in tests, if not elsewhere.

In practice, the ability for classes to control access to their state is more important than the risk of a class using that to do something stupid or malicious (that would be fairly easy to spot).